# At which layer of the network model (e.g OSI) does Winsock2.h send returns?

Tags: winsock

I am looking at a blocking call of [send()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and looking if there is a way to measure the times spent in the function while be able to know what event's occured during that time so that a qualitative analysis can be made about the connection speed etc.

With that, one of the first thing to know is at which layer does the function return success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `send()` API is going to return success nearly immediately IFF there is sufficient buffer space available to hold the data *and* the routing tables still show a way to route the packet to the peer. (It doesn't actually *have* to be able to reach the peer -- simply that the machine must have a next hop available...) If it needs to wait for buffer space to free up, it will. (Watching data being ACKed or sent on the wire ought to be easy with [Wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark).)

Incidentally, the OSI layers are imperfectly applied to the TCP/IP family of protocols; layers 1 and 2 fit very closely, layer 3 is roughly IP routing, layer 4 is roughly TCP, UDP, SCTP, ICMP, and so on. But layers 5, 6, 7 don't have real analogs -- SMTP over TLS might be considered a layer 7 or perhaps the SMTP is layer 7 and the TLS is layer 6 ... it all gets pretty fuzzy very quickly.

It's easier to just talk about the specific layer in the TCP/IP protocol stack that you're curious about. `send()` works with stream, datagram, and raw sockets, so it could straddle multiple layers of the stack -- you could use it to send TCP, UDP, SCTP, or ICMP packets, or scribble directly on the wire if you wish.